# Store UUID as binary in Mysql database with Hibernate/JPA for improving the performance

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, uuid

Now, we define the id as String type with JPA annotation:

```
@Id
private String id;
```

Now we want to save UUID as binary in Mysql, I know JPA have one way to implement it like below:

```
@Id
@Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
private UUID id;
```

But it is big effort to modify String to java.util.UUID type, because I need to modify huge code (a lots of test cases, other calls and so on, anyway we can't do this).

Then I try to use JPA Converter to convert String to bytes and save it, but I found JPA doesn't allow define converter on ID field.

So, please who could provide some possible ways for saving UUID as binary without changing the original String type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `uuid2` ,it offers a broader type range to choose from:

- java.lang.UUID
- a 16 byte array
- a hexadecimal String value

  your id will like :

  `@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
              @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
              @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
              @Id
              private UUID id;`

Comment: I want to define the field as String, but store it as binary, because I don't want to refactor a lot of code

Comment: @Tony instead of refcator your code, you can just add `@PrePersist `(automatic property set before any database persistence) in your entity, e.g->
`@PrePersist
  protected void onCreate() {
     your uuid generation logic...
  }`
now you can add this in your entity class and you don't need to take care of refactor another code. here is it doc https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html